# Differentiating between JSON elements of same name

Tags: javascript, json

I got this JSON file

```
{
"items":[
    {
        "item1":1,
        "description":"descr",  
        "value":0,
    },
    {
        "item2":2,
        "description":"descr",
        "value":1,
    }
],
"shelfName":"top",
"shelfDescription":"The big one"
},
{
"items":[
    {
        "item1":2,
        "description":"descr",  
        "value":0,
    },
    {
        "item2":3,
        "description":"descr",
        "value":1,
    }
],
"shelfName":"bottom",
"shelfDescription":"The little one"
},
```

As you can clearly see, it's structured so the only differing elements (`shelfName` and `shelfDescription`) are on the same level as `items` and I need to select, let's say' an `item1` element of `top` shelf. How one would get to do that without restructurisng the JSON file?

Comment: A valid JSON doesn't contain duplicate keys

Comment: That figures. But what if this one - valid or not - does and I have no way to alter it? (third party JSON of sorts) How would I select the elements I need?

Comment: Find the object whose `shelfName` is `top`, then find the `item1` within its sibling `items`, within that top-level object. Presumably, these objects are all within a top-level array in your JSON.

Comment: @Mark Walters: That doesn't seem to be the case here. Each items/shelfName/shelfDescription triplet is contained within its own object.

Comment: @BoltClock aha, missed that. Although where are the keys for those objects? Unless the parent is an array in which case i'm way off the mark :). Is this the full JSON @roonroon? Where is the parent to those objects shown?

Comment: @Mark Walters: Yeah, that's the assumption I'm going with based on the objects lacking keys.

Comment: Both objects are children of `furniture` object.

Comment: It's a fair assumption thinking about it now. A simple loop with a check for the `shelfName` value to find the object and then navigate down into the items array for that object to get what you're after?

Comment: @roonroon, you mean furniture _array_ right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash's `_.findWhere`. Lodash library here: https://lodash.com/

```
var rawData = [
  { 
    items: [1, 2, 3],
    shelfName: 'top'
  }, { 
    items: [4, 5, 6],
    shelfName: 'bottom'
  }
];
var foundIt = _.findWhere(rawData, {shelfName: 'bottom'});
```

And then `foundIt.items` will give you the items for the bottom shelf!

```
foundIt.items // Returns [4, 5, 6]
```

(This assumes you only have one object where `shelfName` is `bottom`. If you have multiple, you can use `_.where` instead.) Docs for `_.findWhere` here: https://lodash.com/docs#findWhere.

Answer (score 1):

Search the top-level array using `.filter()` then access the relevant property in a `.map()`. Repeat for the inner structure. For your example, assuming `obj` contains the JSON:

```
obj
  .filter(shelf => shelf.shelfName === 'top')
  .map(shelf => shelf.items.filter(item => typeof item.item1 !== 'undefined'))
```

In ES5:

```
obj
  .filter(function (shelf) {
    return shelf.shelfName === 'top'
  })
  .map(function (shelf) {
    return shelf.items.filter(function (item) {
      return typeof item.item1 !== 'undefined'
    })
  })
```

This will return, from your example:

```
[
  {
    "item1":1,
    "description":"descr",  
    "value":0
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ub3sddhk/1/)

```
obj.forEach(function (value) {
    if(value.shelfName === 'top'){
        value.items.forEach(function (value2) {
            if(value2.item1){
                console.log(value2.item1);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

You'll first have to make sure your json is valid by encircling it with `[]`. Then you can loop through the initial array. For every iteration you check if `shelfName === 'top'`. If so then you loop through `items` till you find `item1` and return

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs and the  you might get around this by simply iterating the shelf-objects in the array in a method returning the object that has the right name:

https://jsfiddle.net/kpnu7yfb/

```
var json = {"furniture":[{
"items":[
    {
        "item1":1,
        "description":"descr",  
        "value":0
    },
    {
        "item2":2,
        "description":"descr",
        "value":1
    }
],
"shelfName":"top",
"shelfDescription":"The big one"
},
{
"items":[
    {
        "item1":2,
        "description":"descr",  
        "value":0
    },
    {
        "item2":3,
        "description":"descr",
        "value":1
    }
],
"shelfName":"bottom",
"shelfDescription":"The little one"
}]};

function getShelf(shelfName){
    for(var i=0;i<json.furniture.length;i++){
     if(json.furniture[i].shelfName==shelfName) return json.furniture[i];
    }
}
var topshelf = getShelf("top");
alert("shelf named '" + topshelf.shelfName +"' (" + topshelf.shelfDescription+") has " + topshelf.items.length +" items"  );
```

Answer (score 0):

**Since i can't see any function that allows to input also the item parameter i added my version of the loop using while.**

If the function finds the item it returns an object containing the item information. If nothing is found a string "not found" is returned.

**The function**

```
function getShelfData(shelfName,item){
 var l=o.length,s,sl; // o is your javascript object.
 while(l--){
  if((s=o[l]).shelfName==shelfName){ // o
   sl=(s=s.items).length;
   while(sl--){
    if(s[sl][item]){
     return s[sl]
    }
   }
  }
 }
 return "not found"
}
```

**Usage**

```
getShelfData('bottom','item2');
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/7ektcu0m/3/

**Extra**

I would personally avoid any type of **new** native functions like `forEach`, `map`, `filter` as they are actually slower than a simple loop (`while`/`for`) with which you can achieve the same result.

While this works well for a short list i suggest to restructure the JSON string if you plan to use big datasets.

If this `(s=o[l]).shelfName` seems to be to complex to understand, it caches the object while it's checking it. Doing so you increase the overall performance and save some space.

If you actually read the code you will also notice that i reuse some variables. Again performance is increased and some bytes saved.

if you have any questions just ask

---

**In case i'm wrong here is an example which gets the whole shelf data**

```
function getShelfData(shelfName){
 var l=o.length;
 while(l--)if(o[l].shelfName==shelfName)return o[l];
 return "not found"
}
```

something very similar can then be applied to get the item

```
function getShelfItem(o,item){
 var l=o.items.length;
 while(l--)if(o.items[l][item])return o.items[l][item];
 return "not found"
}
```